# Netbeans me dice "el valor asignado no está en uso"

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios en netbeans y me da la señal de advertencia, no de error y me dice que el valor no esta en uso en todos los case, y al correr el código me permite colocar un número y al dar enter lo único que devuelve es el número. Hice un ejercicio similar y me salió bien, no entiendo porque acá me dice eso.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication15 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
 int dia;
 String diaDeLaSemana;
  System.out.print("Introduzca un número del 1 al 7 para indicar un día de la semana ");

dia = s.nextInt();

switch (dia){
  case 1:
  diaDeLaSemana="Lunes";
  break;
  case 2:
  diaDeLaSemana="Martes";
  break;
  case 3:
  diaDeLaSemana="Miércoles";
  break;
  case 4:
  diaDeLaSemana ="Jueves";
  break;
  case 5:
  diaDeLaSemana ="Viernes";
  break;
  case 6:
  diaDeLaSemana ="Sábado";
  break;
  case 7:
  diaDeLaSemana ="Domingo";   
  break;
  default:
  diaDeLaSemana ="Del 1 al 7 te dije";

    System.out.println("El dia "+dia+" es: "+diaDeLaSemana);
     }  
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

El println encargado de mostrarte el resultado esa dentro del switch case cual no seria correcto ya que siempre el usuario deberia ver un respuesta inclusive cuando haya escogido un valor fuera de rango.

Codigo corregido

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dia;
        String diaDeLaSemana;
        System.out.print("Introduzca un número del 1 al 7 para indicar un día de la semana ");

        dia = s.nextInt();

        switch (dia) {
            case 1:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Lunes";
                break;
            case 2:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Martes";
                break;
            case 3:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Miércoles";
                break;
            case 4:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Jueves";
                break;
            case 5:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Viernes";
                break;
            case 6:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Sábado";
                break;
            case 7:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Domingo";
                break;
            default:
                diaDeLaSemana = "Del 1 al 7 te dije";
        }

        //aqui debe ir este println
        System.out.println("El dia " + dia + " es: " + diaDeLaSemana);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El Switch se usa para obtener un valor de acuerdo a un valor de entrada , revisa la documentaciòn oficial: [Java declaraciòn Switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html),  aquì puedes ver el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Por lo tanto, en tu còdigo, dentro de del `switch` obtienes un valor para un variable en este caso `diaDeLaSemana` , pero para hacer uso de este valor, este debe encontrarse fuera del `switch` :

```
switch (dia){
  case 1:
    diaDeLaSemana="Lunes";
  break;
  case 2:
    diaDeLaSemana="Martes";
  break;
  case 3:
    diaDeLaSemana="Miércoles";
  break;
  case 4:
    diaDeLaSemana ="Jueves";
  break;
  case 5:
    diaDeLaSemana ="Viernes";
  break;
  case 6:
    diaDeLaSemana ="Sábado";
  break;
  case 7:
    diaDeLaSemana ="Domingo";   
  break;
  default:
    diaDeLaSemana ="Del 1 al 7 te dije";
  } 

System.out.println("El dia "+dia+" es: "+diaDeLaSemana);
```